# Use singleton into a class with only static methods and no constructor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have a classes with only static methods, and no constructors in a library, and I need to access properties from a singleton object which is shared across the .razor files in a WebASM project.

- How use singleton into a class with only static methods and no constructor ?

Comment: The static object is _in a library_?

Comment: Yes. The static object is in a library shared across many other classes inside this library.

Comment: And the library references (depends on) your singleton?  Where is that defined?

Comment: where it is created ? it is registered as 
 service -> builder.Services.AddSingleton<DataProviders>(); in program.cs
but the things getting more complex each minute, because i have to have about 12 such services now, and somehow the code start looking ugly..

Comment: 12 services is close to nothing. But look at how they are usually bundled into .UseThisLibrary()`

Comment: You are more than correct, but unfortunately the project is not even halfly done :)
and somehow i just dont like this breaking of the encapsulation through DI..

Comment: DI should not break encapsulation. If it does you have something else wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How use singleton into a class with only static methods and no constructor ?

That is a mismatch. The Singleton is managed by the DI and is created later. Potentially it could be recreated or cleared later on.

So treat them the same: make both objects Singletons (preferred) or make both static.

In general you should avoid the temptation of `static`, especially for state keeping.

Comment: Well.. the point is that there is a lot of classes which have to be shared across the libraries, and a lot of them persists in others, and injecting the singleton into each constructor would be a quite overhead i believe.

Comment: The injection would only add a reference. Don't optimize when you don't have a clear problem.